# quick launch not appearing under look and feel tab

Tags: sharepoint-server, administration, central-administration

I am a beginner in sharepoint and learning some [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DlcQQFiKgs) videos

In the linked video I can see quick launch link under look and feel tab but in my site this is not appearing I dont know the reason

Please see the below screenshot

[image]

I have activated all the features inside site settings->site collection features
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks Like you are using the Publishing Tempalte, In publishing **Navigation option** (this is advance form of the quick launch).

In Team Site you have the **Quick Launch**. But if you enable the Publishing feature on the Site collection, then Quick Launch will disappear and navigation link will appear.

check this for some photo...http://www.jenniferannmason.com/Blog/Post/243/An-Overview-of-Navigation-Options-for-SharePoint-2013---Office-365

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I dont know if I am using publishing template.I am using an admin account from rackspace for practice.How to disable the publishing feature?

Comment: I have deactivated all having publish and now the quick launch appears.Thanks for the answer,+1